# How to set different settings for a mobile theme?

Tags: themes, theme-options, mobile

My desktop version of wordpress theme requires using a 'static' page as the start page as it has custom shortcodes etc.

While this is good, when it comes to my mobile theme, sadly the 'static' page is being displayed and because its a different theme, the shortcodes are not being executed.

Is there a way to tell a mobile theme to display 'blog posts' as the default page and not use a 'static page' as a starting page for the theme?

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, pardon me, but am I right in assuming that this goes into the mobile theme's header (even before the <head> tag)?

Comment: What? Please ask Q on my answer. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap you code up in a conditional:

```
if ( $GLOBALS['is_iphone'] )
{
    // do funky stuff for mini screens
}
```

`global $is_iphone;` will trigger `TRUE` for all mobile devices incl. tablets.

### Edit for WP 3.4+

Now there's [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_is_mobile/) to make checks for `User-Agent`. It's basically a wrapper for `$is_iphone` and does the same.

Comment: Is this a built-in WordPress variable? If so, this might be easier than the way I am doing it now (and was going to suggest) which is by including [MobileDetect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/).

Comment: Yes it is. There'll also be a function wrapper or short API for it with WP 3.4.